# How do I optimize JFrame drawImage for RGBA images?

Tags: java, swing, optimization, jframe, bufferedimage

I'm working on a 2D game in Java using swing JFrame.

At the moment I can get >60fps repainting a grid of 64x64 image tiles, but when I want to add my tree images which are 80x170 each and have transparent edges around the tree, my fps grinds to about 8.

I've considered drawing the trees to their own BufferedImage grid, but it needs to be updated frequently, whenever a player moves or AI moves, etc.

I've noticed using smaller images and drawing them at a larger scale does not help, and am really struggling to see how I can get around this.

Comment: You may want to go to the next step: GPU programming. Good luck !

Comment: @iKiWiXz do you have any resources where I can look into that for java 2D stuff?

Comment: I never did such things in Java, but OpenGL is a safe way to go. http://jogamp.org/jogl/www/ seems to implement it well. PS: it's a whole new level, just do it if you are well motivated (I remember how hard it was in C#).

Comment: @iKiWiXz Ah okay :) I was trying to challenge myself and see what I could do in Java but it does have its limitations

Comment: Well, these limits are not from java, but from your CPU. You may get sightly better performance with C++, but you'll still need GPU developpement to get the real power.

Comment: Sounds strange to me that you can't get more than 8 fps using normal Java2D (the rendering pipeline is already GPU/hardware accelerated normally). Have you made sure your images are "compatible" (`createCompatibleImage(...) `)? Are you using `BufferStrategy`?

Comment: Verify that you are not inadvertently resampling images; critically reexamine your need for 60 Hz refresh.